# Failed Inspection - rust on rotors from not being driven much

Tags: brakes, brake-rotor, inspection

Just attempted to have my car inspected in Vermont and the mechanic immediately said it would fail because of the rotors. He asked if the car has been sitting for a long time, and said that something "isn't even making contact." I was at my dealership (in Massachusetts) just two weeks ago for a tire rotation, and they said nothing, marking the brakes as green for all linings and measurements. I'm trying to find a second mechanic to take a look but I've seen helpful feedback on here before, so what do y'all think?

[image: rear driver]
[image: front driver]

Comment: Go for an “Italian” service.

Comment: Steel and iron rust when wet on this planet ; find a mechanic from this planet. They do seem to show exceptionally little use.

Comment: Rust around the rim shouldn't matter to anyone. There does appear to be some rust on the area in contact with the brake pads though. As Solar Mike said, an "Italian service" will fix that. (If you don't know what "Italian service" means, drive for a few miles with either the gas or brake pedal always pushed right to the floor.)

Comment: I would recommend the Italian service, but the best method would be to find a highway, at 55 or 60 mph do a hard brake untill you are down to 30 mph. Then cruise for a couple miles to let rotors cool. Repeat several times. If that doesn't clear it sufficiently, do it again on the next day.

Answer (score 1):

You are right to question this, those look a bit rusty but that will wear off with use. It's normal for brakes to get some surface rust when a car hasn't been driven. Go drive it with plenty of braking, then go to a different inspection center.